# SMTP email integration in cloud composer

Tags: email, google-cloud-platform, smtp, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to use SMTP email in GCP cloud composer. I have followed the GCP documentation and did the following -

1. Created a secret with my SMTP password (tested with secret name as `airflow-variables-smtp-password` & `airflow-config-smtp-password`)
2. Provided secret accessor role to my svc account
3. Modified email backend and all configs -

```
[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp

[smtp]
smtp_port = 587
smtp_user = ****
smtp_mail_from = ****
smtp_password_secret = smtp-password
smtp_host = smtp.office365.com
```

4. Changed secret backend -

```
[secrets]
backend = airflow.providers.google.cloud.secrets.secret_manager.CloudSecretManagerBackend
```

Below is my email dag which is subject to fail (tested with email operator as well) -

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_hello():
 pppp
 return 'Hello Wolrd'

args = {
    'owner': '***',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': "2021-09-14",
    'email_on_failure': True
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='mail_testing',
    default_args=args,
    ) as dag:
    python_task = PythonOperator(
                task_id='email_task',
                python_callable=print_hello,
                email_on_failure=True,
                email= ['***'],
                dag=dag
            )
```

When running the dag, I am seeing it is looking for sendgrid to send the email.

```
[2021-09-29 17:42:20,958] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - /opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/sendgrid/utils/emailer.py:122 PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching Sendgrid credentials from environment variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.
[2021-09-29 17:42:21,081] {taskinstance.py:1503} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1158, in _run_raw_task
    self._prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks(context, task)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1333, in _prepare_and_execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, task_copy)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1363, in _execute_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/email.py", line 79, in execute
    send_email(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/email.py", line 55, in send_email
    return backend(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/sendgrid/utils/emailer.py", line 122, in send_email
    _post_sendgrid_mail(mail.get(), conn_id)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/sendgrid/utils/emailer.py", line 141, in _post_sendgrid_mail
    response = sendgrid_client.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail_data)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_http_client/client.py", line 277, in http_request
    self._make_request(opener, request, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/python_http_client/client.py", line 184, in _make_request
    raise exc
python_http_client.exceptions.UnauthorizedError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
[2021-09-29 17:42:21,084] {taskinstance.py:1546} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I am missing!

Comment: This issue has been raised in this issue tracker. We cannot provide an ETA at this moment but you can follow the progress in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/201755887) and you can ‘STAR’ the issue to receive automatic updates and give it traction by referring to this [Link](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#starring_an_issue).

Answer (score 0):

> PendingDeprecationWarning: Fetching Sendgrid credentials from environment variables will be deprecated in a future release. Please set credentials using a connection instead.

[These docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.5/howto/email-config.html#email-configuration) describe configuring Sendgrid credentials in a connection. I would follow them, as they include steps for troubleshooting.

The other possibility is that it's an issue with your Sendgrid credentials. You can test your sendGrid credentials are valid by [sending a test-email via a curl request](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/api-getting-started#send-your-email-using-the-api).